# MultiView And JavaScript (or jquery) Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, multiview, activeview

how can i get multiview in javascript or jquery ?

below code always returns null : (Javascript)

```
var MultiView = document.getElementById("MultiView1");
```

and below code is not null but not work :(jquery)

```
var MultiView = $("*[id$='TextBox1']");
```

what is the going on about that?

can u give me plz a sample code for checking ActiveViewIndex With JavaScript or Jquery!

i added the below code because of comment :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Keyup._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

    <%--    <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    document.onkeyup = onkeyupOfDocument;

                    function onkeyupOfDocument(evt) {
                        var evt = evt || window.event;
                        //alert(evt.keyCode);
                        //var MultiView = $("*[id$='TextBox1']"); 
                        var MultiView = document.getElementById("MultiView1");
                        alert(MultiView);
                    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

thanks in future advance

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML markup of the element(s) you're trying to select? It is impossible to tell if the selector is correct without knowing what the markup looks like.

Comment: i added aspx (html) code as you said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay but here is what you are looking for :

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var activeViewIndex = $('.multiviewContainer').attr('activeKey');

            alert(activeViewIndex);

        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="multiviewContainer" CssClass="multiviewContainer">

        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                   View 0
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                   View 1
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                   View 2
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View ID="View4" runat="server">
                   View 3
            </asp:View>

        </asp:MultiView>

    </asp:Panel>

</asp:Content>
```

and code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string activeView = MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex.ToString();
        multiviewContainer.Attributes.Add("activeKey", activeView);
    }
}
```

Comment: really really thanks / but my goal is not changing multiview activeviewindex / i only want to check multiview ActiveViewindex for doing something...(i can not change multiview with divs - because i used multiview in code behind many many times)